# Getting error while try to connect with SQL server using System.Data.SqlClient library in Xamarin iOS app on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, ios, sql-server, visual-studio, xamarin

I use Xamarin Forms iOS App and try to connect with database, but I receive error like this:

Is there a way to fix this problem ?

[image: System.Data.SqlClient Error]

The Code:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

private void SQLConnection()
        {
            string connectionString = @"Server=192.168.0.12,3306;Database=MeteoAPP;User Id=username;Password=pass;Trusted_Connection=false";

            string selectQuery = String.Format("CALL nearest3(24.65, 42.20, 1)");

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
                    command.Connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                LabelSQL.Text = exception.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: please do NOT post errors as images.  And you should really, really avoid connecting directly to a db server from a mobile client

Comment: From security and scalability points of view, don't have mobile apps connecting directly to database - hide your database servers behind a web API of some kind. Secondly, do you really have SQL Server listening on port 3306? The typical port for default SQL Server instances is 1433. 3306 is the default port for MySQL.

Comment: Yes I really have sql server on port 3306, and my question is still there without answer how to fix that..

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild the solution ?Sometimes it is helpful when libraries aren't acting as expected.